# What are the black egg-like lumps with green bubbles in LEGO Jurassic World?

Tags: lego-jurassic-world

As I roam the hub islands I've come across these black egg-like structures with green bubbles/glow coming from them - none of the characters I've unlocked yet seem to be able to interact with them, and I can't read the contents of the hexagon that appears when I'm near them.

What are they and how do I interact with them?

[image: Black bubbling eggs?]

Comment: Just a guess (I haven't got this far in the game yet), but the Prima Guide mentions a dinosaur ability called "Goo Spit" with this description: Dilophosauruses can spit venom goo at black LEGO objects to destroy them.

Comment: That sounds about right. The icon could well be a Dilophosaurus - I don't have one yet either sadly, but suggest you add that as an answer now ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Prima Guide, there is a dinosaur ability called "Goo Spit" with the following description:

> Dilophosauruses can spit venom goo at black LEGO objects to destroy them.

Comment: Now I've moved closer to my TV, I can see they clearly are Dilophosauruses. Thanks :)